# Description Logics and Ontologies: How to denote role domain-restrictions to blank nodes

Tags: logic, semantic-web, owl, ontology, description-logic

**Request for assistance denoting a domain-restriction to a blank node.**
[image: Modelling a Many-to-Many (Relational) Table with a Blank Node]
*Figure 1: Modelling a many-to-many relationship with a blank node.*

*Business Rule: An Enrolment maps one Student to one Section, once.*

**My attempt:**

```
∃hasStudent.⊤ ≡ ∃hasSection.⊤ ≡ ∃grade_code.⊤ 

i.e. "the set of individuals that have some value for the role 'hasStudent' is the same set of individuals that have some value for the role 'hasSection' ...e.t.c."
```

I assume equivalence here instead of inclusion since the inclusions would be in both directions.

**Restricting further:**

```
∃hasStudent.⊤ ≡ ∃hasSection.⊤ ≡ ∃grade_code.⊤ ≡ =1hasStudent.⊤ ≡ =1hasSection.⊤ ≡ =1grade_code.⊤

i.e. "the set of individuals that have values for the roles 'hasStudent', 'hasSection' and 'grade_code', have one and only one value for them."
```

**Assistance or comments on correctly denoting the domain-restrictions of the object properties in figure 1 would be appreciated.**

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

OWL's Open World assumption is going to prevent you from finding "the set of individuals that have values for the roles 'hasStudent', 'hasSection' and 'grade_code', have one and only one value for them."

However, using SPARQL, you could create an ASK query that does just what you are asking for:

```
ASK {
   SELECT (count(?student) AS ?stcount) (count(?section) AS ?secount) (count(?course) AS ?ccount)
   WHERE {
      ?indiv :hasStudent ?student .
      ?indiv :hasSection ?section .
      ?indiv :grade_course ?course .
   } GROUP BY ?student ?section ?course
   HAVING (stcount = 1 && ?secount = 1 && ?ccount = 1)
}
```

A bit akward syntactically, since the aggregates need to be computed by a SELECT statement.  The ASK will return true if the 'constraints' (see the HAVING clause) are all true and false otherwise.

For future reference the [SHACL (RDF Shapes Constraint Language)](https://www.w3.org/TR/shacl/) work at W3C is intended to shore up these kinds of constraint violation problems that are not possible to answer with OWL.

Comment: We're getting somewhere. Thank you. Now, referencing blank node instances is not a goal here; tightly defining the properties via domain (and range) restrictions is. Above, is my attempt in description logics to do this... Your SPARQL query is what I want to enforce in an OWL R-Box... Does the DL attempt above properly denote this restriction? And would it's OWL correlary be valid, too? **+1 for the query and providing a reference.**

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your intent correctly, you want these restrictions to apply to any use of these properties rather than only for a specific class.

Under this assumption, you can achieve this by declaring the properties functional and setting their domain to `C`. In Functional syntax:

```
Prefix(owl:=<http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>)
Prefix(rdf:=<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>)
Prefix(xml:=<http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace>)
Prefix(xsd:=<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>)
Prefix(rdfs:=<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>)

Ontology(
Declaration(Class(<urn:test:C>))
Declaration(ObjectProperty(<urn:test:hasSection>))
Declaration(ObjectProperty(<urn:test:hasStudent>))
Declaration(DataProperty(<urn:test:grade_code>))

FunctionalObjectProperty(<urn:test:hasSection>)
ObjectPropertyDomain(<urn:test:hasSection> <urn:test:C>)

FunctionalObjectProperty(<urn:test:hasStudent>)
ObjectPropertyDomain(<urn:test:hasStudent> <urn:test:C>)

FunctionalDataProperty(<urn:test:grade_code>)
DataPropertyDomain(<urn:test:grade_code> <urn:test:C>)

SubClassOf(<urn:test:C> ObjectIntersectionOf(ObjectSomeValuesFrom(<urn:test:hasSection> owl:Thing) ObjectSomeValuesFrom(<urn:test:hasStudent> owl:Thing) DataSomeValuesFrom(<urn:test:grade_code> rdfs:Literal)))
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So my goal is to describe the ontology in the figure without giving the blank node a type. I'm wanting to restrict the domains of its properties (which you have done) not by giving the blank node a type and referring to it, but by describing the node.